# Move Upsells after Related products section in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

How can i change order of Up-sell & Related products sections on single product. It need to show first related products and then up-sell

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following that will move upsells after related products:

**1) For Most themes:**

```
add_action( 'init', 'move_upsells_after_related' );
function move_upsells_after_related( ) {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_upsell_display', 15 );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_upsell_display', 25 );
}
```

> **Now in some themes like Storefront**, a custom hook is used.

**2) For Storefront theme** only you will use instead:

```
add_action( 'init', 'move_upsells_after_related' );
function move_upsells_after_related() {
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'storefront_upsell_display', 15 );
    add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'storefront_upsell_display', 25 );
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.